# Multiplicity of imaginary roots of real polynomial

Tags: polynomials, roots

I am studying ODEs and I found out that the solution to the linear problem
$$
\begin{cases}
\dot{x} = Ax\\
x(0) = x_0
\end{cases}
$$
where $A \in M_n \mathbb{R}$ can be written as
$$
x(t) = \sum_{j = 1}^k e^{\mu_j t}\sum_{l=0}^{m_j -1} \frac{t^l}{l!}(A - \mu_j I)^l \xi_j
$$
where the $\mu_j$s are the distinct roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and have multiplicity $m_j$. Also, $\xi_j \in \ker((A - \mu_j I)^{m_j})$ for all $j = 1, \dots, k$.
While studying the asymptotic behaviour, one looks at the real part of the roots $\mu_j$.
I came across a theorem in which the solution $x(t)$ was decomposed as $x(t) = x_-(t) + x_0(t)$ where
$$
x_-(t) = \sum_{\substack{j = 1\\ \mathrm{Re}\mu_j < 0}}^k e^{\mu_j t}\sum_{l=0}^{m_j -1} \frac{t^l}{l!}(A - \mu_j I)^l \xi_j
$$
and
$$
x_0(t) = \sum_{\substack{j=1\\ \mathrm{Re}\mu_j = 0}}^k e^{\mu_j t}\xi_j
$$
This suggests that the roots that have real part equal to zero have multiplicity 1. Is that true? How can one prove that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. $p(x) = (x^2+1)^2 = (x-i)^2(x+i)^2$ has purely imaginary roots $\pm i$ of multiplicity $2$. Consider for example

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ -1 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1   \\ 0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$
Its characteristic polynomial is $p(x)$.

Comment: Thanks! But how do you explain the decomposition $x(t) = x_0(t) + x_-(t)$, assuming there are no roots $\mu_j$ for which $\mathrm{Re}\mu_j > 0$? The only way for that to be true is that $m_j$ = 1 whenever $\mathrm{Re}\mu_j = 0$, isn't it?

Comment: I do not know your theorem. But as you can see from my updated answer, $\pm i$s are the distinct roots of the characteristic polynomial of $A$ and have multiplicity $2$.

Answer (score 0):

The decomposition is possible because if $\mathrm{Re} \mu_j = 0$, then the algebraic multiplicity $m_j$ is equal to the geometric multiplicity. This in turn means that
$$
\ker(A - \mu_j I) = \ker((A - \mu_j I)^2)
$$
and hence
$$
\ker(A - \mu_j I) = \ker((A - \mu_j I)^l) \quad \forall \, l \geq 1
$$
Thus, in the decomposition over the roots with null real part, the only term that survives is the one corresponding to $l = 0$.